# Using A PHP App in Wordpress

Tags: php

I have an Internet Radio Station and I have been designing a new site using WordPress. It's the first time I've used WordPress and I'm not familiar with it.

On our existing site we have a simple php app that displays the album art, Artist Name, Song Title, Album Name and Release Year of the currently playing song.

It takes the song information from a txt file using the web export function of the radio station software we use. It does not access a database.

The app has 3 files: config.php (with hard coded info), display.php and radiodj.php.

It runs on it's own and never needs a backend. And to display the album art etc on our front page is a simple code in a block

```
<div align="center">
<div id="auto"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
```

So, as I am not at all familiar with WordPress I need some suggestions as to how I can get this to work in WordPress.

Any help or advice you can give would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Doesn't it come with a JavaScript file? Or does it print it's JavaScript per PHP into the page?

Comment: No Javascript. Just the three files previously mentioned and a css file

Answer (score 0):

WP is different than PHP code. Content is stored in a database, and displayed via template files, which come with your theme.

Which template displays your content? Take a look at the Template Hierarchy (ask the googles/bings/ducks, or look in the Codex via the link below).  For instance, a page is usually displayed with a template file called 'page.php' in your theme folder. If you want to add code to a page, then copy that template file, give it a new name, then add your code in the proper spots.

Too much info to try to explain here. Perhaps build your understanding of WP by starting here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page . There are also tons of sites that can help with your knowledge; one is WPBeginner . You can find more via the googles/bings/ducks.

Comment: I tried adding the above mentioned code to the front page as HTML but that didn't do anything.

Do I have to turn it into a plugin?

Comment: Nope. Create a template from your current theme's page.php (or equivalent). Then add your code in the area where the post content is output. Details in the Codex link, under templates area. Lots of articles can be found on the googles/bings/ducks about creating a new template from an existing one. Just remember that templates are theme-specific; you'll have to do it again if you change themes.